# How to fetch data from more than one table in spring integration database poller

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

I have a db poller to fetch rows from more than one table. So I wrote two pollers to fetch data independently using the below code and it's working fine, but the problem with the below code is redundancy. So there any better way to achieve this?

```
//Poller 1 for table one:   
 
@Bean
    public MessageSource<Object> jdbcMessageSource() throws SQLException {
        return new JdbcPollingChannelAdapter(dataSourceConfig.getDataSource(), "select * from db.table_name_one");
    }
    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow pollingFlow() throws Exception {
        return IntegrationFlows.from(jdbcMessageSource(),
                c -> c.poller(Pollers.fixedRate(10000)))
                .handle(List.class, (payload, headers) -> {
                    transferExecutor.handleMessage(payload);
                    return null;
                })
                .get();
    }

//Poller 2 for table two: 
    @Bean
        public MessageSource<Object> jdbcMessageSource1() throws SQLException {
            return new JdbcPollingChannelAdapter(dataSourceConfig.getDataSource(), "select * from db.table_name_two");
        }
        @Bean
        public IntegrationFlow pollingFlow1() throws Exception {
            return IntegrationFlows.from(jdbcMessageSource1(),
                    c -> c.poller(Pollers.fixedRate(10000)))
                    .handle(List.class, (payload, headers) -> {
                        transferExecutor.handleMessage(payload);
                        return null;
                    })
                    .get();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

If data in those tables are fully different, then your solution is correct.
Since you have different tables, it is really logical to have different services to handle them.

Imaging you would do JPA for those tables, so you probably would have different entities and different Spring Data Repositories.

However if data is similar you probably could consult with your DBA how to be build `JOIN` select for those two table or even have a `view` in DB to perform a simple query from your application.

There is definitely nothing Spring Integration can do for you. This is just not this framework responsibility to do some heavy lifting for interaction with RDBMS.

Comment: If run pollers like this, will it run in parallel threads?